# same git version, same Linux distro, different git paging settings

Tags: git, pager

I am utterly baffled by this:

I have two machines, both running `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`. On both of them, the `git` version is the standard one that comes with the distro, `2.17.1`. They have *identical* `.bashrc` files for the main users I access them with, and identical `.gitconfig` files in the respective home directories.

As far as I can tell, no other default `git` configuration files (as listed e.g. by [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)). The common `.bashrc` sets the `PAGER` environment variable, but the `.gitconfig` file says nothing about paging options.

My issue:

On one machine `git branch` defaults to listing branches in the pager (`less`) and on the other it does not. I have tried this seconds ago, in a small repo I cloned on both machines almost simultaneously (the [zathura](https://github.com/pwmt/zathura) pdf viewer).

My question:

What explains the discrepancy?

Comment: Different `/etc/profile`? Different `~/.bash_profile`? Different env var `$LESS`? Different repositories (one has a long list of branches, the other just one or two)?

Comment: Take a look at your environment (`env` or `printenv`). Look for `$PAGER`, `$GIT_PAGER`, `$LESS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestions (in both of the two first replies to my original question) on `$LESS` seem to have done the trick:

`$PAGER` was identical and `$GIT_PAGER` was unset in both cases, but there was a difference in `$LESS`: as soon as I set it (even to blank!), `git` defaults to displaying the output of `git branch` in the pager.